# React-intl not working from Link component

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I getting error multi language redirect click Link component but I press F5 it's works. How to fix this error. Help me!

I press F5 it's works

```
 <Link href="/account/signin">
  <a><FormattedMessage id="navAccount.signIn" /></a>
 </Link>
```

It getting variable name I declare in json file.

Comment: Try removing nested `a` and adding `defaultMessage` to `FormattedMessage`.

Comment: @Clarity I try removed a but it not redirect. I'm use Link of nextjs

Comment: @Clarity and I using multi language so I can't adding defaultMessage in that

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `variable name declared in JSON`, you're missing `IntlProvider` from your component tree it looks like.